# Python getting part of string based on condtion

Tags: python, pandas, string

Hi I am pretty new to Python and is currently looking for a way to effectively get a part of a string from a column based on a condition.

I currently have a column with the address.
It looks something like this.

```
data = {'addr': ['Seoul Gangnam Apgujeong 38-5', 'Seoul Songpa Jamsil 40-1 5-1302', 'Jeju Jeju Aewol 31-5', 'Busan Haeuondae Centum 70-1 7-141']}
```

I want to extract the second and the third value of the string.
So the result should look something like this

```
data = {'addr': ['Gangnam Apgujeong', 'Songpa Jamsil', 'Jeju Aewol', 'Haeuondae Centum']}
```

Any sort of feedback would be appreciated!!
Thank you in advance!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use list comprehension with `split`, slicing, and `join`:

```py
data = {'addr': ['Seoul Gangnam Apgujeong 38-5', 'Seoul Songpa Jamsil 40-1 5-1302', 'Jeju Jeju Aewol 31-5', 'Busan Haeuondae Centum 70-1 7-141']}
output = {'addr': [' '.join(s.split()[1:3]) for s in data['addr']]}
print(output) # {'addr': ['Gangnam Apgujeong', 'Songpa Jamsil', 'Jeju Aewol', 'Haeuondae Centum']}
```